# How to make redirection in Apache HTTP with Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, redirect

I have installed in my Linux server an Apache HTTP Server (the main) and an Apache Tomcat 7 Server.

I want that all requests that are made for projects hosted in Tomcat to be redirected by the Apache HTTP respectively.

I didn't do that until now, so have anyone some thoughts and suggestions on this?

I read something about `mod_jk`, `mod_proxy`, `mod_jserv`.

What is the best choice for my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use mod_proxy, put this in your `<VirtualHost>`:

```
ProxyPass /project-one http://127.0.0.1:8080/project-one
ProxyPassReverse /project-one http://127.0.0.1:8080/project-one
```